# Document create software using AngularJs?

Tags: laravel, document

I am currently developing a web application using `Laravel` and `AngularJs`. One of the requirement in document module is, that they want to create, update documents like `Google Docs` or `Zoho Docs`.

I googled but couldn't find a solution.

How can I implement it? It seems like that it is a big task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a really big deal. There is an example flow how an implementation could work like:

- keep track every change (for example keydowns) on client side
- create a patch message
- send the patch to a backend server
- notify all of the other users that the content has been modified and send the patch to apply
- apply the patch on the client
- repeat each and every time something is changing

Of course the backend has to accept messages from all of the clients and distribute it to all of the other ones which has the same document open. Google Docs is working in a similar way you can check it in the developer tools of Chrome for example or check [operational transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).

***Edit***

Use the API of one of the mentioned services instead of building an own module. https://www.zoho.eu/docs/zoho-docs-api.html

Comment: Thank you the answer, How and where save data in server? Can you suggest me

Comment: For example you can have a document on the server and patch it every time a patch arrives. There are other possibilities to keep the files versioned, but those could have some serious drawbacks as well.

Comment: If I want to create a word document, how can I save content inside the document? if directly saving word document in server? then how can I edit it again?

Comment: Google created an online editor and it required *years* of of work with a *lot of members* to do it. I do not think that any of us could create an editor like it alone in reasonable time. You can give a try to edit text files from multiple browsers it will be a great challenge. But I think documents are really hard to manage, so I would not really do this if I were You.

Comment: Its nice.. wot about zoho writer https://www.zoho.com/docs/writer.html. it also need lot of people and lot of work?

Comment: It must have been a hard project with a lot of workers as well. It would be the best for You to use their api: https://www.zoho.eu/docs/zoho-docs-api.html This way you can have the functionality without writing the whole application by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For goole docs you could use the following with angular js:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/